# Search MP3/Ogg files by tags/parameters from the command line

Tags: files, find, audio, mp3, ogg

Is there any utility to search MP3/Ogg files by tags (or other characteristics) from the command line? (e.g. finding all audio files longer than 10 minutes with genre set to 'Rock').

I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7243216), which suggests using `mp3info`, but it's only for MP3 files and the proposed solution isn't the most elegant thing. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many [FUSE](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=Main_Page)-based ["Media File Systems"](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=MediaFileSystems).  [tagsfs](https://gna.org/projects/tagsfs) or [pytagsfs](http://www.pytagsfs.org/) might fit your needs, not sure if it's readily available, though (e.g. there's no official Debian package as far as I can see).

Be aware that *traversing* the resulting (virtual) file systems is not advisable; i.e. just `ls` your query, don't `find`.

Comment: Those look like the most interesting approach. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.pytagsfs.org/ is no longer accessible. It appears that project is not maintained since middle of 2011.
Same thing with tagsfs. It would be nice to revise correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

See if ffmpeg -i filename helps.